# библиотека fstream, запись в файл с помощью метода в классе кириллицей c++

Tags: c++

пишу систему аренды автомобилей(как проект для новичка) на плюсах и столкнулся с такой проблемой: в программе можно добавлять новые автомобили и писать для них их марку. в качестве базы данных использую текстовый файл и туда записываю марку авто, но как только пытаюсь что то записать на русском, вместо символов кириллицы я вижу какие то китайские буквы. возможно это как то связано с тем что я сделал запись в файл через метод в классе, а setlocale у меня стоит в главной функции main. кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, если да то как решили? если понадобится я могу скинуть код

Comment: https://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score -1):

дело в кодировке, в которой вы открываете файл.
Чтобы в ОС Windows с этим не морочиться, скачайте Notepad и там открывайте с помощью верной кодировки 1251, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: utf8 без bom, если точнее

Comment: @TheRyuTeam utf8 с bom, если еще точнее

Comment: У меня с bom под visual studio крокозябры